# Issue sorting from mysql database more than one word

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, filter, cpu-word

I have a PHP code that runs a MySQL query to sort some output data by a filter selected.

The problem that I have is when I filter by more than 1 word, i.e. when I filter by color it works fine for RED, YELLOW, etc.. but not for BLUE NAVY.

I thought it would be enough by adding `'"` but it is not.

Here is my current code:

```
 <?php
$colors = $con -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1 ASC");
$colors ->execute();
while ($colorBoxes = $colors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='color' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you vlue navy in your table ?

Comment: yes, it exists in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around your array indexes.

Change: `$colorBoxes[color_base1]`

To: `$colorBoxes['color_base1']`

[Bonus points](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php):

```
printf(
    "<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='color' value='%s' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   %s</font><br />",
    $colorBoxes['color_base1'],
    $colorBoxes['color_base1']
);
```

Also, your form data is probably going to submit pretty weird when the input `name` field has a space in it. Try a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` after the form is submitted to see what the deal is, but I would suggest not using spaces in your `color_base1` field.

Answer (score 0):

your sql looks right and your code looks right also but since you are using `SELECT DISTINCT`
this may is causing problem and it select only one word from two words (it will distinct from blue and navy) so there is an other method more better and recommended .
+ you are doing `ORDER BY` so no need here for `DISTINCT` if you are using `ORDER BY` because they do the same job.

- if your are using `item_descr` type `ENUM` or `SET` then they will be ordered by column index not column values.

try doint this instead

```
SELECT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1 ASC
```

here [**DEMO SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef573/1)